# I'm very new to programming, and wanted to know how to display the JButton on my GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am new to programming and have just started learning GUI and was wondering why my GUI isn't showing my button, also i want it to exit the application as it is pressed.  I'm unsure on what to do next, could someone help me pls :) I would be very greatful.

```
public class Main implements ActionListener {
    public static void GUI(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton exit = new JButton();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1080, 720, 1080, 720));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        exit.setSize(10, 20);
        exit.setBounds(100, 400, 100, 600);
        frame.add(exit);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //exit.add(exit);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Gabe's GUI app");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        exit.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried/searched so far? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026807/how-to-display-a-jbutton-and-give-it-functionality) helpful?

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager of the content pane of a JFrame is the `BorderLayout`. You can only add a single component to each area of the `BorderLayout`.

```
frame.add(exit);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you don't specify a constraint when adding the component, then BorderLayout.CENTER is used.

So in your above code "panel" replaces "exit" in the CENTER.

Try:

```
frame.add(exit, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

> I am new to programming

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are many examples you can download and test.

Start with the examples in `How to Use BorderLayout`. The example will also show you how to better structure your code so the GUI is created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. All components should be created on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

To close the `JFrame` on click on exit, write `exit.addActionListener(this);` and in actionPreformed method write `frame.dispose();`.